# strange error with Object name in Python

Tags: python, runtime-error

I am learning Python from [this web page](http://woodpecker.org.cn/abyteofpython_cn/chinese/ch11s06.html) (it's in Chinese, please just focus on the code.) And I want to practice the code by myself using Python 2.7.3 on Windows 7. But I find a very strange error with the Object name. The code is as follows:

```
class Person:
    '''Represents a person.'''
    population = 0

    def __init__(self, name):
        '''Initializes the person\'s data.'''
        self.name = name
        print '(Initializing %s)' % self.name

        # When this person is created, he/she
        # adds to the population
        Person.population += 1

    def __del__(self):
        '''I am dying.'''
        print '%s says bye.' % self.name

        Person.population -= 1

        if Person.population == 0:
            print 'I am the last one.'
        else:
            print 'There are still %d people left.' % Person.population

    def sayHi(self):
        '''Greeting by the person.
       Really, that\'s all it does.'''
        print 'Hi, my name is %s.' % self.name

    def howMany(self):
        '''Prints the current population.'''
        if Person.population == 1:
            print 'I am the only person here.'
        else:
            print 'We have %d persons here.' % Person.population

David = Person('David')
David.sayHi()
David.howMany()

kalam = Person('Abdul Kalam')
kalam.sayHi()
kalam.howMany()

David.sayHi()
David.howMany()
```

I got this error report (last two lines) when running these code. But when I replace the Object variable 'David' with 'Swaroop' or some other names, the code works fine! I don't know how this happen.

```
(Initializing David)
Hi, my name is David.
I am the only person here.
(Initializing Abdul Kalam)
Hi, my name is Abdul Kalam.
We have 2 persons here.
Hi, my name is David.
We have 2 persons here.
Abdul Kalam says bye.
There are still 1 people left.
David says bye.
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'population'" in <bound method Person.
__del__ of <__main__.Person instance at 0x00000000026D91C8>> ignored
```

Comment: Your output suggests that "when I replace the Object variable 'David' with 'Swaroop' or some other names, the code works fine" is not true.

Comment: i didn't got any error. . everything is fine. .

Comment: @wRAR Would you please provide more info? I ran this code and replaced the Object name **David** on two Windows platforms, the results are coherent to my description "when I replace the Object variable 'David' with 'Swaroop' or some other names, the code works fine". Would you please run this code? Thanks!

Comment: You show the output of a program that prints "Swaroop" and shows the exception.

Comment: @wRAR Yes, I have updated the error report. Thank you very much!

Comment: @namit on which platform and what version of Python did you use?

Comment: @Bloodmoon: i run it in `ipython notebook` on `windows xp` and my python version is `2.7`

Answer (score 2):

The exception arises when the `__del__()` method is called during the interpreter shutdown. It's not guaranteed that anything is available at that point and in your cases it looks like the `Person` variable is already destroyed. You should either ignore this problem or stop using `__del__()`.

Answer (score 2):

The only explanation I can find comes from the [`__del__` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) (in the warning block):

> Due to the precarious circumstances under which `__del__()` methods are invoked, exceptions that occur during their execution are ignored, and a warning is printed to `sys.stderr` instead. **Also, when `__del__()` is invoked in response to a module being deleted** (e.g., when execution of the program is done), **other globals referenced by the `__del__()` method may already have been deleted or in the process of being torn down** (e.g. the import machinery shutting down).

To verify this, I've added a `print globals()` in the `__del__` method:

- First call: `Person` appears in the globals with a proper class object

  ```
  {'kalam': None, '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__package__': None, 'Person': <class __main__.Person at 0x00000000021D7168>, '__name__': '__main__', 'David': <__main__.Person instance at 0x00000000022B0748>, '__doc__': None}
  ```
- Second call: `Person` still appears, but now with a `None` value

  ```
  {'kalam': None, '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__package__': None, 'Person': None, '__name__': None, 'David': None, '__doc__': None}
  ```

**Now, why does changing the variable name `David` *could* change this behavior?**

The order of destruction is probably deterministic, but the rules are not documented: we are in the realm of the "implementation defined". In this case, on my particular Python interpreter,  renaming `David` to `A` does change the destruction order, and the `Person` class objects gets destroyed last.

This is not a fix per se, it's just a weird side effect: you cannot reasonably rely on destruction order.

Comment: So, my further questions would be, why another Object name works, but **David** does not? What's the difference the Object names bring while the code is runing (or complied)?

Comment: I don't get different outputs. On the other hand, using `__del__` might be a bad idea anyway. **`__del__` is not a destructor.**

Comment: @Matthias, many tutorials just take **__del__** as the destructor, if using **__del__** is a bab idea, then what should I use to accomplish the same function of **__del__**? Thank you!

Comment: Use an external counter. I added an answer with a short (and obvious) example where `__del__` is not called.

Answer (score 1):

To show an example of `__del__` not being called:

```
class Referencer(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __del__(self):
        print("__del__ {}".format(self.name))

foo = Referencer('foo')
bar = Referencer('bar')
baz = Referencer('baz')
foo.x = bar
bar.x = foo

del foo
del bar
del baz
```

You would expect an output like this:

```
__del__ foo
__del__ bar
__del__ baz
```

You get (at least with Python 2.7):

```
__del__ baz
```